# android library tests did not run against obfuscated(proguard) code

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, android-library, android-testing

Android library: Try to run tests against obfuscated code

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}
```

source sets

```
src/main/
src/androidTest
```

run tests:

```
gradle connectedAndroidTest
```

The classes.jar inside the mylib-debug.aar is obfuscated by proguard (as expected),
but connectedAndroidTest is not running against proguarded code.  I intentionally
commented out some `-keep` in proguard-rules.pro, but no error occurs at runtime.

Looked at the test apk mylib-debug-androidTest.apk under build (not on device) , the classes inside the apk are not obfuscated. why?  The classes inside mylib-debug.aar are obfuscated.

### Update

I tried 
[Android Unit Tests with proguard enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26482119/android-unit-tests-with-proguard-enabled)

the answer is for app, not for android library. It did not work.

### Update

How to configure `connectedAndroidTest` so that it includes the proguarded .aar
and exclude the main output?

Comment: Can you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/37840781/1597616

Comment: have tried testProguardFile before. no luck.